# Reacting to changes in components in angular avoiding location.reload()

Tags: angular, service

in this simple app im building in angular i have a aesthetic problem , cause any time i commit a change on my login or signup component changing the user auth state , the other components in the app do not listen it until i reload the page with a function reload().

Lets say i have a login function in my service that set a user in my localstorage once is authenticated.Then through this service other components would update or expose information based on thayt user authenticated

```
AuthService

signIn(signedinUser: SignInModel) {//SigInModel is a predesigned model 
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`/signin`, signedinUser).pipe(
      map((userData) => {
        console.log(userData);
        ...some code...
        sessionStorage.setItem('username', signedinUser.username);
        return userData;
      })
    );
  }

isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
   
    return !(user === null);
 }//this method once the logged user is stored in local storage through the action of signing in 
  triggered in the fucntion signIn() return the condition of his existence or not in the 
  local storage, being reference for other components in order to show or not information according 
  with the auth
```

Then on my Login  Component

```
...some code...
   loginUser() {
     this.authService.signIn(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          console.log('Sorry something went wrong ');
        } else {
          this.routerMethod();//routering after login
        }
      });
    }

  async routerMethod() {
    await this.router.navigate(['/']);
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.reload();
    }, 500);//Wrong not aesthetic !!!
  }
```

Literally in this part i trigger the processs of login passing the method initialized in the service having as parameter all the values of a Reactive Form(this.loginForm.value), then being susbcribed to that method, if is successful i just call a router method to another component showing all elements available for the user authenticated, but by itself it doesnt work thus i have to insert a page reload in order to commit the changes onçe the router acts(Thats wrong i guess).

Then in the component listening the changes i just look on my local storage if the user is authenticated or not accessing the method initialized in the service that checked if the local storage was null or not

```
Some Component

isAuth:boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isAuth = this.authService.isUserLoggedIn().valueOf();

......do some .....
}
```

How could i rid off that page load , and on same time make reactive all components to any change commited from service once the user logs in.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Yes im tryiing angular by myself , thus i',m missing some stuff

Comment: Thanks MikeONe....any suggestion?

Comment: The Tour of Heroes is a great start (https://angular.io/tutorial). Egghead has some good tutorials as well (I think some free even). Loads available on youtube as well. 
You’ll quickly start seeing how updates and change detection works in Angular. Good luck man!